# Good font to use with Unicode musical symbols?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I can't seem to find a font with good support for the [unicode musical notation symbols](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf). The following shows the fonts Symbola, GNU FreeSans and Musica. The first two characters are the unicode characters [U+2669](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2669/index.htm) and [U+266A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266A/index.htm). The subsequent musical notes are in the [music-specific Unicode range](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf).

[image]

Unfortunately, all three of these fonts display the characters in the Unicode musical symbols range significantly smaller than other characters (including the first two musical symbols in the miscellaneous range). The second two fonts also display these symbols with a different line height from other symbols.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to a font that displays these musical symbols consistently, with the same line height as other characters, and without making them appear significantly smaller compared to text.

Comment: Please provide your test-sample-text not only as bitmap, but also as something we can copy and paste for testing.

Comment: Have you looked at the fonts which come with Denemo (http://denemo.org/)?

Comment: I know this post was eight years ago... but did you ever find a good font? :) Seems I can no longer use the suggested answer

Answer (score 4):

Go to [MyFonts](http://myfonts.com) and click on Advanced Search, then make a search with what you want to see, most likely this one:

Available Characters V Contains V  "your SAMPLE TEXT ♩♫♬♭♮♯♪ TEXT"

Then MyFonts will nicely list you all capable typefaces with the musical characters right next to some sample text of your own choice. And you can pick according to the rendering and to the pricing and licensing etc.

Comment: Sadly I have to report that MyFonts no longer lets users search for "available characters"; a real loss for minority languages that do not show in the list of supported languages. At the time of writing, my answer was correct; now no longer works. Sorry.

Comment: I couldn't find a way in Google fonts to search by supported characters, but you can add sample text. I found a font called Noto Music which has all the music characters: https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Music?preview.text=test%20%E2%99%A9%E2%99%AB%E2%99%AC%E2%99%AD%E2%99%AE%E2%99%AF%E2%99%AA%20test&query=music